# How to configure Eclipse with Web driver PHP Binding and selenium stand alone server ,so that we can run test cases from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I am getting lots of instruction material related to "how to configure eclipse for java and selenium" , but my requirement is i want to use eclipse for PHP and i want to connect it with selenium stand alone server and PHP unit so that i can run my selenium test cases from eclipse.

i have already installed XAMPP , PHPUNIT. i have already downloaded selenium stand alone server and Eclipse for php .

can any one please suggest how to do  that.

Comment: go through http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html

You may get some idea.

Comment: @HemChe i read the link u have given , but here no instruction is given how i can connect eclipse with xamp ,selenium standalone server and phpunit. i need the steps only . because currently i am using notepad++ as editor and i have to run my selenium test cases from command prompt ,  but i want to run my selenium test cases from eclipse.

Comment: Configuring Eclipse with PHPUnit
http://pkp.sfu.ca/wiki/index.php/Configure_Eclipse_for_PHPUnit

For Selenium WebDriver, you just need to add Selenium standalone server and selenium PHP bindings jar files to buildpath.

Comment: @HemChe for php buinding there is no jar files .

We run php buind selenium test case in the below way

in one command prompt we start the stand alone server and in another command  we use the command   phpunt pathto php file

Comment: you can use third party bindings provided in the following links.                      
    https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver
    https://github.com/Nearsoft/PHP-SeleniumClient
    http://code.google.com/p/php-webdriver-bindings/

Source: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/ (check the third party language bindings section)

Comment: @HemChe  i am already using php-webdriver-bindings for writing the selenium testcases . and i have already run few testcases  , but i want to run those test cases from eclipse now , i think u r not getting my point .  currently i  run those testcases  through command prompt , i already told the steps  how i run in my previous comment.  i just need to  connect the eclipse with my selenium buinding and selenium server so that i can run those test cases from eclipse. please tell the steps how connect eclipse with selenium stand alone server and phpbuinding.